# Using list comprehension as condition for if else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have the following code which works well

```
list = ["age", "test=53345", "anotherentry", "abc"]

val = [s for s in list if "test" in s]
if val != " ":
    print(val)
```

But what I'm trying to do is using the list comprehension as condition for an if else statement as I need to proof more than one word for occurence. Knowing it will not work, I'm searching for something like this:

```
PSEUDOCODE
if (is True = [s for s in list if "test" in s])
print(s)
elif (is True = [l for l in list if "anotherentry" in l])
print(l)
else:
print("None of the searched words found")
```

Comment: You dont need a list comprehension here because you're not comprehending a list, just trying to write a clever one liner

Comment: "if val != " "" but `val` is a list... that is what list comprehensions do, and is their purpose, **they create lists** using mapping/filtering operations on iterables. `val` will **never** be equal to a string

Comment: The question isn't very clear.  Do you have a list of words, and want to check if certain words are in it?

Comment: Since Python 3.8 you have the "walrus" operator `:=`. The question isn't very clear, but maybe that's what you're looking for? `if(sl := [s for s in list if "test" in s]): print(sl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, avoid using reserved words like "list", to name variables. (Reserved words are always branded as blue).

If you need something like this:

```
mylist = ["age", "test=53345", "anotherentry", "abc"]
keywords = ["test", "anotherentry", "zzzz"]
    
    for el in mylist:
        for word in words:
            if (word in el):
                print(el)
```

Use this:

```
[el for word in keywords for el in mylist if (word in el)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`any` in python allows you to see if an element in a list satisfies a condition. If so it returns True else False.

```py
if any("test" in s for s in list): # Returns True if "test" in a string inside list
    print([s for s in list if "test" in s])
```

Comment: this do the same work twice, you can just do the list comprehension first and print it only if you get any result

Answer (score 0):

First, please don't use "list" as a variable. There is a built-in function called list()...

Could work like this:

```
list_ = ["age", "test=53345", "anotherentry", "abc"]
val = [s for s in list_ if "test" in s]                #filters your initial "list_" according to the condition set

if val:
    print(val)                                         #prints every entry with "test" in it
else:
    print("None of the searched words found")
```

Comment: why pointlessly replace the list comprehension with a less idiomatic `filter`? Also, `if len(val) > 0` should just be `if val`, but I think the OP actually wants `if len(val) > 1`, not sure though

Comment: changed it, you were right

Answer (score 0):

Since a non-empty list tests as True (e.g. `if [1]: print('yes')` will print 'yes') you can just see if your comprehension is empty or not:

```
>>> alist = ["age", "test=53345", "anotherentry", "abc"]
>>> find = 'test anotherentry'.split()
>>> for i in find:
...   if [s for s in alist if i in s]:i
...
'test'
'anotherentry'
```

But since it is sufficient to find a single occurance, it would be better to use `any` like this:

```
>>> for i in find:
...   if any(i in s for s in alist):i
...
'test'
'anotherentry'
```